# Retrieve WooCommerce products data and pass it to a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I have about 300 WooCommerce products with latitude and longitude information as custom fields that I want to add to a map created with Leaflet.

I'm currently stuck trying to create the markers for each product inside the map because I'm not getting the products information correctly.

This is my PHP code used to retrieve the products data (I'm currently testing with a category with only 4 products to make this easier):

```
$products = wc_get_products( array( 'status' => 'publish', 'limit' => -1, 'product_cat' => 'talleres' ) );
```

On the JavaScript side, this is the code I'm using:

```
  var locaciones = [
    [ <?php foreach ( $products as $product ) { echo get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'coord_lat', true ); } ?>, <?php foreach ( $products as $product ) { echo get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'coord_long', true ); } ?>, "<?php foreach ( $products as $product ) { echo $product->get_title(); } ?>", {icon: iconoUrbe}, "https://permalink.com/", "https://i.imgur.com/xH761ML.jpg" ]
  ];

  for (var i=0; i<locaciones.length; i++) {

    var lat = locaciones[i][0];
    var lon = locaciones[i][1];
    var popupText = locaciones[i][2];
    var icono = locaciones[i][3];
    var permalink = locaciones[i][4];
    var imagen = locaciones[i][5];

    var locacionMarcador = new L.latLng(lat, lon);
    var locacion = new L.marker(locacionMarcador, icono);
    mapita.addLayer(locacion);

    locacion.bindPopup("<div class='titulo'>" + popupText + "</div>" + "<br><a href='" + permalink + "' target='_blank' class='imgborde'>" + "<img src='" + imagen + "' width='250' height='141' />" + "</a><br><a href='" + permalink + "' target='_blank'>Más información</a>");
  }
```

That code outputs the following for the latitude:

```
-26.910714-26.978776-26.968379-27.540683
```

That output isn't working because when added to the JavaScript, the map doesn't recognize it, because it looks like this in the array:

```
 [ -26.910714-26.978776-26.968379-27.540683, -68.036321-67.941395-67.505819-68.225849, "Taller de fotografía time-lapseTaller de fotografia nocturna de paisajeTaller de introducción a la fotografía digitalTaller de revelado con Lightroom Classic", {icon: iconoUrbe}, "https://permalink.com/", "https://i.imgur.com/xH761ML.jpg" ],
```

So, instead of getting all the information together, I need to get the latitude, longitude, etc, for every single product separately.

I haven't added the icon, permalink and image url information yet because it breaks the map and I can't check anything for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json_encode (built-in php function) to put stuff into a JavaScript variable. This will keep things a lot more organized and maybe help with your problem.

```
<?php

$products = wc_get_products([
    'status' => 'publish', 
    'limit' => -1, 
    'product_cat' => 'talleres'
]);

$locations = array_map(function ($product) {
    /** @var WC_Product $product */
    return [
        'lat' => get_post_meta($product->get_id(), 'coord_lat', true),
        'long' => get_post_meta($product->get_id(), 'coord_long', true),
        'title' => $product->get_title(),
        'icon' => '...',
        'url' => '...',
        'img_url' => '...',
        // if easier, just include the popup html here and not the other stuff
        'popup_html' => '',
    ];
}, $products);

?>

    <script>
        var locations = <?= json_encode($locations); ?>

            // assuming you have jQuery. If not, use a for loop.
            $.each(locations, function (index, location) {
                console.log(location);
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: I added the jQuery script to my code and the console is showing the products information separately now, formatted as json.
But now I don't know how to pass that information to the JavaScript portion to make it work with the map.

Comment: Each location should be a JavaScript object containing whatever indexes are set in the PHP array mapping function. You should be able to use location.lat, location.long, etc. to retrieve any values that you want. This should handle passing the data to JS... whether or not your map code works is another question.

Comment: After some research I was able to make it work. But now I have one last issue, the custom icon isn't showing. I believe it has to do with the "{}" characters.

This is how the Leaflet code looks like when it has a custom icon: `var locacion = new L.marker(-25.910714, -67.036321, {icon: customIconName});`

I tried this but the map just doesn't load: `var locacion = new L.marker(-25.910714, -67.036321, {icon: location.icon});`

I tried adding this to the product but it doesn't work either: "{icon: customIconName}".

Comment: I moved around some code and I was able to make it work. Thank you so much for your help, your initial code helped me solve this.